# Error al cargar datos del formulario

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, razor

Estoy haciendo un formulario que carga datos y lo muestra en una vista con MVC.

**Customer.cs**

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Web;



namespace Formulario2.Models

{

    public class Customer

    {

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Amount { get; set; }

    }

}
```

**CustomerController.cs**

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.Mvc;

using Formulario2.Models;



namespace Formulario2.Controllers

{

    public class CustomerController : Controller

    {

        // GET: Customer

        public ViewResult DisplayCustomer(CustomerController objCustomer)

        {

            return View(objCustomer);
        }

        public ActionResult FillCustomer()

        {



            return View("FillCustomer");

        }

    }

}
```

**FillCustomer.cshtml**

```
@model Formulario2.Models.Customer

@{

    Layout = null;

}



<!DOCTYPE html>



<html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>FillCustomer</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayCustomer", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))

        {

            <p>

                @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Code,"Código")

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)

            </p>

            <p>

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Nombre")

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

            </p>

            <p>

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, "Cantidad")

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)

            </p>

            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />



        }



    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**DisplayCustomer.cshtml**

```
@Model Formulario2.Models.Customer
  @{

    Layout = null;

}



<!DOCTYPE html>



<html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>DisplayCustomer</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div>

        El codigo del cliente es @Model.Code<br />

        El codigo del cliente es @Model.Name<br />

        @if (Model.Amount > 100)

        {

            <p>Este es el cliente privilegiado</p>

        }



        else

        {

            <p>Este es el cliente normal</p>

        }





    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Cuando lleno los datos del formulario, me salta una excepcion en la línea 15 de DisplayCustomer.cshtml

```
El código de usuario no controló Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

  HResult=-2146233088

  Message='Formulario2.Controllers.CustomerController' no contiene una definición para 'Code'.

  Source=Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly

  StackTrace:

       en CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )

       en System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)

       en ASP._Page_Views_Customer_DisplayCustomer_cshtml.Execute() en C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\practicando\ASP mvc\Formulario2\Views\Customer\DisplayCustomer.cshtml:línea 15

       en System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()

       en System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()

       en System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)

       en System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)

       en System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)

       en System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)

       en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)

       en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)

       en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)

  InnerException:
```

Si le pongo model con minúscula, me dice que `Code` y `Name` no existen en el contexto actual. Lo mismo con el model del if.

Anteponiendo a @model Formulario2.Models.Customer, no se soluciona.

**Que puede ser?**

Comment: Sería bueno que mostraras cuál es la línea 15, mostrando qué investigaré para solucionarlo

Comment: porque `public ViewResult DisplayCustomer` y no `public ActionResult DisplayCustomer`?

Comment: La línea 15 es El codigo del cliente es @model.Code <br/>

Comment: Estaba así en el ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu método de acción (Action Method) DisplayCustomer debe de recibir un objeto del tipo de tu model, es decir del tipo 'Customer' ademas de que debe de estar decorado para recibir un http post.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult DisplayCustomer(Customer objCustomer)
    {
        return View(objCustomer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en el controlador. Estas pasando a la vista un controlador:

```cs
    public ViewResult DisplayCustomer(CustomerController objCustomer)
    {

        return View(objCustomer);//Aquí esta el error.
         //Estas pasando un tipo CustomerController cuando deberias pasar un Customer
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

no es `@Model Formulario2.Models.Customer` es `@model Formulario2.Models.Customer`

con minúscula, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752749/different-between-model-and-model) un problema similar, pero esta en inglés.

Comment: me anduvo con mayúscula